# Как развернуть цикл FOREACH() в обратном порядке?

Tags: javascript

```js
document.querySelectorAll('div').forEach((s, i, arr) => {
    s.innerHTML = i+1;
  });
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Как обернуть `index (i)` в обратную сторону?

в итоге должно быть так

```
<div>3</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>1</div>
```

С ответом все понятно а как быть с комментарием в таком исполнении

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('change', function(){
    document.querySelectorAll('div').forEach((s, i, arr)=>{
      this.checked  === true ? s.innerHTML = i+1 : s.innerHTML = ''; //Как тут использовать  Arr.reverse().forEach()
    });
})
```

```html
<input type="checkbox">
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

не понятно

Comment: `Arr.reverse().forEach()`

Answer (score 2):

```js
document.querySelectorAll('div').forEach((s, i, arr) => {
    s.innerHTML = arr.length - i;
});
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```